# Design Pattern to free an object in C

Tags: c

When programming in C, we usually create data structures that we initialize, then free when it is no longer needed. For instance, if we want to create a dynamic array of double, it is common to declare

```c
struct vector {
    double *data;
    int size;
    int capacity;
}
typedef struct vector vector;

vector *v_new(int n) {
    vector *v = malloc(sizeof(vector));
    v->data = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    v->size = n;
    v->capacity = n;
    return v;
}
```

The question is about the common patterns for a free function. In C, the function `free` accepts the NULL pointer and does nothing. Is it a common pattern to design `v_free` functions in such a way, or are they usually expecting a non-NULL pointer? To make it clear, would you expect this implementation

```
void v_free(vector *v) {
    if (v != NULL) {
        free(v->data);
    }
    free(v);
}
```

or this one ?

```
void v_free(vector *v) {
    free(v->data);
    free(v);
}
```

This question is asked because we began to teach C to undergraduate students in prep school in France, and we don't have that much experience in "C Design Patterns".

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: If `v_free` called irrespective of whether `vector` is allocated or not, then 1st case would be the better approach. It would avoid accessing of  member variable on null-pointer which is UB.

Comment: Avoiding a NULL dereference when free'ing buried allocations (e.g. your `data` member) is fine, and obviously the first code is equipped to handle that. However, don't forget that both of these code examples are inescapably susceptible to indeterminate/dangling pointer malfeasance.  Ideally your code "knows" a pointer is either non-null and non-dangling, or null. more often than not it is the danglers and indeterminate pointers that will bite you, and only the caller can take the responsibility to protect against those.

Comment: my 2 cents, might as well go with the 2nd one. Checking for `NULL` isn't foolproof. If you `free` a pointer, it does not get set to `NULL`, leaving it susceptible to double `free`s, which is UB. If you fail to initialize a pointer it may not be initialized with NULL, so you're still vulnerable to `free`ing an invalid pointer. It's always up to the programmer to do the right thing. Having said that, I have no problem with the first method.

Answer (score 5):

You can't access `v->data` if `v` is NULL. So if there is a chance of that, you must do the version which checks for that, which is better written as

```
void v_free(vector *v) {
    if (v != NULL) {
        free(v->data);
        free(v);
    }
}
```

---

If `v` should never be NULL here, it's perhaps better to add an assert to make the assumption explicit:

```
void v_free(vector *v) {
    assert(v != NULL);
    free(v->data);
    free(v);
}
```

That way the programmer will notice they are doing something wrong.

---

Note that neither version detects a dangling pointer, ie. pointer which points to already destroyed object. This includes pointing to memory already freed (ie. you'd have double free here) or by pointer having pointed to local variable which is not in scope any more.

Comment: There is no need to write `assert(v != NULL)` in every function, unless you are unsure. The program will crash anyway, and the programmer can then use a debugger to see why it crashed.

Comment: @user253751: is it always crash for null pointer deference, as it is UB?

Comment: @user253751 Asserts should be disabled on release build anyway, and it serves a self-explanatory code, better that a comment. It is not quite guaranteed that `free(v->data);` will crash on `v` being NULL, though it's extremely likely.

Comment: @TruthSeeker On real computers, which run memory-protected operating systems, actually yes. I would not be surprised to find this guarantee somewhere in the OS or compiler manual, even though C does not guarantee it. Assuming that you are only intending to detect programming mistakes and you are not writing an embedded application or operating system kernel, this is not one of the forms of UB that you need to be defensive against.

Comment: Even the well-known NULL-related Linux kernel optimization bug which caused a security vulnerability - would have crashed if run in a normal process (not a kernel)

Comment: @hyde it's v->data, not &v->data, it will crash the program to even try and get the address. &v->data would be an offset from null

Comment: @user253751 I think I was unclear on what I meant, and misrrad what you wrote, never mind.

Answer (score 3):

> The question is about the common patterns for a free function. In C, the function free accepts the NULL pointer and does nothing. Is it a common pattern to design v_free functions in such a way, or are they usually expecting a non-NULL pointer?

This is going to be a matter of opinion.

My opinion is, unless you have a good reason otherwise, program defensively. ***Do the thing that will make debugging a mistake easier***. Make `v_free` error on a null pointer. Something as simple as an [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert).

```
void v_free(vector *v) {
    assert(v != NULL);

    free(v->data);
    free(v);
}
```

Consider if we quietly ignore the null case. Did the caller *intend* to pass a null pointer, or was it a mistake? We don't know. If it was a mistake, the program continues merrily along and probably mysteriously crashes elsewhere. This makes debugging more difficult.

Consider if we assume `v_free` will always receive a non-null pointer. If it does `free(v->data)` is undefined behavior. At best a messy error, at worst the program continues merrily along and probably mysteriously crashes elsewhere. This makes debugging more difficult.

But if we provide an error, the mistake is stopped and revealed. Do the same thing for all your vector functions.

"But what if I want to pass a null pointer?" That should be infrequent, don't optimize for it. Make the caller do the check. If they really need to do it frequently, they can write a little wrapper function.

```
void v_free_null(vector *v) {
    if( v == NULL ) {
        return;
    }
    v_free(v);
}
```

Comment: On real systems (as opposed to deathstation 9000s) it will already crash on a null pointer.

Comment: @user253751 Does "Deathstation 9000" mean "Windows"?

Comment: no, it's a hypothetical machine that always does the worst possible thing in response to undefined behaviour (usually involving murdering the programmer).